# Import Image to ImageButton

Tags: java, android, image, android-imagebutton

I'm trying to import image to my app into `ImageButton`. When the user clicks on it will go to the Gallery and select the photo. But it doesn't appear after I select the image from the Gallery or external storage.

xml code

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/foodimbutton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:onClick="ibC"
/>


<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/itemName"
    android:hint="enter the item Name"
 />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/itemDesc"
    android:hint="enter the item Descrption"
/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/itemPrice"
    android:hint="enter the item Price"
/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add the Item"
    android:onClick="AddtheItemButtonClcied"
/>
```

java code

```
public class AddFood extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageButton imageButton;
    Intent galleryIntent;
    private static final int GALLREQ = 1;
    private EditText name,desc,price;
    private Uri uri = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_food);

        name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.itemName);
        desc = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.itemDesc);
        price = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.itemPrice);
    }

    public void ibC (View view) {
        galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        galleryIntent.setType("Image/*");
        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent,GALLREQ);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == GALLREQ && resultCode == RESULT_OK ) {
            uri = data.getData();
            imageButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.foodimbutton);
            imageButton.setImageURI(uri);
        }
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest

I didn't forget the permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: When is method ibC called?

Comment: its called when u click on ImageButton

Comment: But, your image button is not declared on your code.

Comment: its declared by id foodimbutton

Comment: imageButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.foodimbutton);

Comment: Did you try to display your uri in log or toast to see where it is pointing to?

Comment: no i did not...

Comment: I don't see the method ibC called here, did you leave it on purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
public class Demo2 extends AppCompatActivity {

private ImageButton ib;
private final int GALLREQ = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.demo4);
}

public void ibC (View view) {

    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(galleryIntent , GALLREQ);

}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == GALLREQ && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        ib = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ib);
        Log.e("Uri", "*******" + uri.getPath());
        ib.setImageURI(uri);
    }

}
}
```

demo4.xml:------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:id="@+id/ib"
    android:onClick="ibC"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: the image doesn't Appear in the ImageBoutton after selected it from the Gallery   !!! Empty

Comment: i tryed - in the Emalutro nothing Appear - in my phone its Appear very small ,,, i tryed different images .. is there way to select the size?

Comment: Try to change property scaleType of the imageButton (in XML) to for example fitXY.

Comment: yeah its coool man its Appear very good in the phone ,, in the Emulator nothing .. thank u Rabee (:

Answer (score 0):

I think the button you mentioned is the image button you showed above. If that is the case you need to implement onClickListener() for that button. That is where you call your method by passing that view. There are a tone of examples on the web on how to implement that. Here is a sample,

```
// Create an anonymous implementation of OnClickListener
private OnClickListener myListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
       ibC(v);
    }
};
//call this inside your onCreate() method
imageButton.setOnClickListener(myListener);
```

Let me know if you have any other questions.